# missing gstreamer plugin

Tags: gstreamer

Whenever i open my webcam with cheese it automatically stops. I think the problem is because of some gstreamer plugins missing. Where can I get this plugin?

The following is the output of gstreamer-properties

`sushil@sushil-Vostro-3550:~$ gstreamer-properties`

```
(gstreamer-properties:6150): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkDialog.has-separator

(gstreamer-properties:6150): Gtk-WARNING **: Unknown property: GtkDialog.has-separator
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'artsdsink'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdsink'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosink'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'glimagesink'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sdlvideosink'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lmjpegsrc'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'qcamsrc'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'v4lsrc'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'esdmon'
 gstreamer-properties-Message: Skipping unavailable plugin 'sunaudiosrc'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will install all available gstreamer plugins.

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-*
```